# Avoid generating errors when using unsupported HTML features

Tags: javascript, html

On my index.html site I perform a feature check. Old browser users will be redirected to a site telling them to update their browser:

```
<script>
if (!CSS.supports('display', 'flex')) 
    location.href = 'old-browsers.html';
</script>
<div style="display:flex;"></div>
```

As you can see I first check if flex box is supported and later I use a flex box. (The feature check is in the header. I use flex boxes for my layout somewhere on the site.)

It works. The problem is that old browsers may throw an error when the flex box is actually used. So it's a little ugly.

I want to have a solution which doesn't use features which are not supported.

I could redirect new browser users to new-browsers.html and then use the flex box there. But then the URL for the main site is ugly.

I hope you see the point.

Comment: Using an `else`?

Comment: FYI, it looks like you're reinventing [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/).  It's a great utility for this sort of thing.

Comment: How old does a browser have to be to not support the `Function` constructor?!?

Comment: Also what exactly does "is there a way to p" mean?

Comment: @Pointy It looks like IE 4 might do the trick?  1998.

Comment: @Amy use a foreign library if I can do it on my own in 10 lines of code? :-)

Comment: @somega The library does a lot more, a lot better.  It's better than reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply put your `new Function` code inside an `else` block:

```
if (typeof Function == 'undefined') {
  location.href = 'old-browsers.html';
} else {
  var f = new Function('return true;');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit 2:** It would be a much cleaner design to check if a feature is supported *when the feature is about to be called*. This would make it easier to work with multiple JS files.

The initial approach I posted works fine if all code is in one JS file, but may cause problems whe multiple JS files are in play (a function may be called before the compatibility checking).

```js
if(function1) { //if function1 is supported
  function1();
}
else {
  location.href = 'some_link.hmtl';
}

//function2 could be in a separate JS file

if(function2) { //if function2 is supported
  function2();
}
else {
  location.href = 'some_link.hmtl';
}
```

---

Your code as is should work without raising errors, if you put it all in a single `<script>` tag.

**Edit:** Turns out no need for the code to be in the same script tag either; your approach as is should work fine.

Javascript is an ***interpreted*** language, not a ***compiled*** one, meaning that statements will be evaluated one by one at runtime. Therefore, if the browser is too old, one of the if conditions should be satisfied and the `location.href` line will execute immediately, without looking at the function calls after it.

```html
<!-- feature check -->
<script>
if (typeof Function == 'undefined') {
    // this line will immediately redirect, and the code below it will not be reached
    location.href = 'old-browsers.html';
}

//using the functions
var f = new Function('return true;');
```